# KeyError: 'Not Found' when deleting key from a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate through a Python dictionary using a for loop and then delete one of the keys/value pairs but I'm getting a KeyError: 'Not Found.

Here is my Code.

```
cars = {
    "brand": "Tesla",
    "model": "Model S Plaid",
    "year":  2021,
    "color": "black"
}

cars_copy = {**cars }
print(cars_copy)

for x in cars_copy.keys():
    result = cars_copy.get("color")
    if result:
        del cars[result]
        print(cars)
```

Here is the ERROR:

> del cars[result]
> KeyError: 'black'

Comment: `color` is not a key in `cars` so the `get()` call gives a `result` of `"Not Found"`. You then try to delete *that* from `cars`, but `"Not Found"` is also isn't a key. Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, just seen that I have made changes but still getting an error  del cars[result]
KeyError: 'black'

Comment: You need to delete by key, not by value.  Hence:  `del cars['color']`.

Comment: If you want to delete a entry from dict, you should use the key to delete it. Not value. For eg. `cars.pop("color", None)`

Comment: Side note, When deleting dict items in a loop, you don't need to copy the whole dict, only the keys, e.g. to a list: `for x in list(cars.keys()):` and because the `.keys()` is called automatically: `for x in list(cars):`

Comment: Hello, @VPfB I'm trying to iterate through this dictionary but I'm not allowed to cast the dictionary items to a list I can only create a shallow copy or deep copy. I have used used the same method to illustrate how one can add elements to the dictionary while iterating, however the same method just doesn't work when I try to remove an item from the dictionary while iterating.

Comment: @IsaacTonyloi The `for` loop line in my comment will not modify your dictionary in any way. (but the `del` in the loop body will). Anyway, it was just a note. The code you have posted does not need a loop at all - note that the `x` variable is never used.

Answer (score 0):

`result` will have the value and not the key of the dictionary after the execution of `result = cars_copy.get("color")`. Update your code as below.

```
cars = {
     "brand": "Tesla",
     "model": "Model S Plaid",
     "year":  2021,
     "color": "black"
 }
cars_copy = {**cars }

print(cars_copy)
{'brand': 'Tesla', 'model': 'Model S Plaid', 'year': 2021, 'color': 'black'}

result = cars_copy.get("color", None)
if result:
    del cars['color']
    print(cars)
{'brand': 'Tesla', 'model': 'Model S Plaid', 'year': 2021}
```